# Xamarin Forms(Android): ListView Swipe up to cancel pull to refresh

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm working on a xamarin forms project, and we've enabled pull to refresh on list view. Everythings working, however I've observed that on iOS the pull to refresh can be cancelled then proceeds with scrolling by doing the following:

1. Pull down and hold it
2. Pull up(Note: don't let go while pulling down then up).
3. You'll see that pull to refresh did not proceed and the screen will scroll down instead

On Android however, it is not the case. The pull to refresh is stuck and it will not scroll down. How can I make it so that it will scroll down instead?

For reference, you can also try this on the facebook app.

Comment: You will have to post code for this, i think if i am not wrong ios provides this feature by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a workaround by creating a custom renderer for ListView and made an override to OnInterceptTouchEvent. Tracked the position of initial touch and when the delta of Y changes from more than 0 to less than 0(finger swiped down then returned to initial position), I reset the touch by dispatch MotionEventsAction.Cancel and MotionEventsAction.Down.